# Oppermann's conjecture

Tags: number-theory

I will try to prove oppermann's conjecture using prime number theorem. I evaluated limit at infinity to know if $\pi(x^2-x)<\pi(x^2)<\pi(x^2+x)$ is applicable for very large numbers. 
$ \frac{\pi(x^2)}{\pi(x^2-x)}=\frac{x^2/\ln x^2}{x^2-x/\ln (x^2-x)}$
$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{\pi(x^2)}{\pi(x^2-x)}=\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{x 
log (x^2-x)}{(x-1)\log (x^2)}$
$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{\pi(x^2)}{\pi(x^2-x)}=\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{\frac{1}{y} \log\frac{1}{y^2}-\frac{1}{y}}{(\frac{1}{y}-1)\log\frac{1}{y^2}}$
$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{\pi(x^2)}{\pi(x^2-x)}=1$ 
Similiarly, $\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{\pi(x^2+x)}{\pi(x^2)}=1$

This value will be equal to one only at infinity but there is no number equal to infinity hence both values will be greater then one.It will approach one as the number grow larger but will never be equal to one.

So $\pi(x^2-x)<\pi(x^2)<\pi(x^2+x)$

Comment: This is nonsense. $$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x-1}{x} = 1,$$ but $x-1 < x$ for all $x$.

Comment: @mrf, that doesn't give a counter-example to the type of reasoning done here.

Comment: This method of "proof" also "shows" that $\pi(x) < \pi(x+\epsilon)$ for every $\epsilon>0$.  So not only are there infinitely many primes, but they are dense on the real line...Very powerful stuff.

Comment: A better version of mrf's example might be $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x+\sin(x)}{x} = 1$ - it's true that the limit is $1$, but it doesn't say anything about whether $x+\sin(x)\lt x$ or $x+\sin(x)\gt x$.

Answer (score 1):

Your argument is incorrect. You simply assert without argument that $\dfrac{\pi(x^2+x)}{\pi(x^2)}$ is $1$ only at infinity. But this is precisely what you are supposed to be proving.

Comment: This sounds like a variant of the freshman misconception that a function can never cross its asymptotes.

Answer (score -3):

I just found this forum and I am really happy that I did. 
Well, I am a little rusty but let me try it.... What Chris Eagle meant by showing 
$\frac {π(x^2+x)}{π(x^2)} = 1$ is you cannot just assume it is $= 1$

We all know that $ 0+1=1 $ and $ 1+1=2 $ but there is actually a pretty proof behind it :-) so you should show everything in detail.

So, back to the question/proof......

$\forall x > 1$

1.)
$π(x2−x) < π(x2)< π(x2+x)$

2.) 
$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{π(x^2)}{π(x^2−x)} = \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{ \frac{x^2}{ln(x^2)}}{{\frac{(x^2−x)}{ln(x^2-x)}}} = \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^2ln(x^2-x)}{(x^2-x)ln(x^2} = \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x^2*ln(x^2-x)}{2ln(x)(x^2-x)}$

3.) detour -> $ x^2-x = y \Rightarrow $substitute $ ln(x^2-x) $ with  $ ln(y)  $ just for making it more clear. We did not do anything strange just a little bit more readable.

4.) $\lim_{x,y\to\infty} \frac{x^2ln(y)}{2ln(x)y}$

5.) final detour $$$$
    By the rules and properties of the natural algorithm we know that 
    $$$$ $\lim_{y\to\infty} ln(y) = \infty $ for $ y\to\infty$

That leads to the conclusion that $$$$
$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{π(x^2)}{π(x^2−x)} = 1$

I hope I am not that rusty.... :-)

Comment: I think I have to correct myself.....it looks like I missed something.... $ \frac{\infty}{\infty} $ is actually not really determent !! Maybe I am rusty after all.... Not really important if one fragment is a little bit bigger than the other

Comment: No, that is not what I meant at all.

Comment: So why don't you enlighten us.....

Comment: I've already said what I meant. I don't need you to tell anyone what I *really* meant.